# Why did I see the following pop-up message only now?

Tags: discussion

For quite a while, I have access to various review queues, but only *today* I got the following pop-up (actually individually for each queue):

[image: PopUpCongrats]

Why is that?

PS: It seems to be astronomy SE specific as far as I can tell, that's why I am asking here.

Comment: I think it's a new thing for beta sites, I got that message as well.

Comment: I just realized that I got it on the main site as well, just with a bit of time delay

Comment: It's also on the meta sites too :)

Answer (score 4):

This is because of [a new network-wide initiative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363485/274942) to better educate folks about the review queues. It should show up on every site on which you have review privileges, but won't show up if you don't have access to the review queues - that's likely why you didn't see it on the majority of the sites you use.